# dd SCSI image into VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, scsi

I have a very old Linux box (actually dating from 1998) wich used to run a legacy system. The system was discontinued, but the data must be available for consults. My idea was to make a image from the hard disk and then convert it to a virtual machine, to be started on demand.

I followed some tutorials, but never got it running, because VirtualBox keeps me telling it cant boot it. So to the steps/details:

- It's a SCSI disk.
- I used the dd command to make the raw image.
  $dd if=/dev/sda1 | gzip > of=/mnt/flash/img.gz
- Unpacked in the destiny.
- I used the vboxmanage convertfromraw command to convert it to VDI.
  :\vboxmanage convertfromraw img.img img.vdi --format VDI
- I created a SCSI controller on configuring the virtual machine, and added the image to it.
- Get the error "FATAL: No bootable media found!"
- After some more searching, i decided to boot a linux livecd with the disk image.
- The machine booted, but couldnt find the disk.
- Switched the image from SCSI controller to IDE controller.
- Now i can find the disk, but still cant boot it.

Now, i think it might be the SCSI thing. Somewhere on these steps i need to inform its a SCSI drive, since its been treated as a regular IDE almost all the time. Thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm thinking where you made the image and ran it through GZIP is the sticking point.

Comment: Edited the question. I did the zip and unzip as i should.

Comment: Perhaps you needed to dd the entire drive (/dev/sda)?  Grabbing just /dev/sda1 will miss the master boot record.  Once you dd the drive, you've taken all the SCSI-ness away.  The image will look the same for an IDE disk.